# my listview not refresh how to show new values every time

Tags: android

im insert arraylist on listview inside function cal that function on background  but problem is if i click multiple times on button listview show duplicate values how to refresh or restrict listview to show only current values every button click remove all previous???
          Button e01;

```
           static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> school_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> menu_name = new ArrayList<String>();

static ArrayList<String> dish_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> day = new ArrayList<String>();

static ArrayList<Long> Vacation_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Vacation_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Vacation_Date = new ArrayList<String>();

String mydate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.category_list2);
    }



            void clearData() {

    Category_ID.clear();
    school_name.clear();
    menu_name.clear();
    dish_name.clear();
    day.clear();

    Vacation_ID.clear();
    Vacation_name.clear();
    Vacation_Date.clear();

}







              public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    getDataTask() {
        if (!prgLoading.isShown()) {
            prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(8);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        parseJSONData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);

        if ((Category_ID.size() > 0) || IOConnect == 0) {

            listCategory.setAdapter(cla);





        } 
    }
}






                 public void parseJSONData() {
    clearData();
    SelectMenuAPI = Utils.Schoolmenu + Cat_name + "&lid=" + SchoolLevelId;
    zero1check = valll.toString();


    URL = SelectMenuAPI;
    URL2 = URL.replace(" ", "%20");

    SelectMenuAPI2 = Utils.SchoolVacation;

    clearData();
    URL3 = SelectMenuAPI2;
    URL4 = URL3.replace(" ", "%20");

    if (zero1check.equals("0"))
        byweekdate = Todayday + 1;
    else if (zero1check.equals("1")) {
        byweekdate = Todayday + 2;

    }

    try {

          Log.i("url",""+URL2);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams
                .setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(URL2);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
          String str2 = "";
        str2=   _response2;

           JSONArray school = json2.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = school.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (count == 1) {
                        count = 0;
                        break;
                    } else

        if (object.getString("Schedule").equals("weekly")) {

    if (object.getString("day").equals(Todayday)) {
    Category_ID.add((long) i);
    school_name.add(object.getString("school_name"));


       dish_name.add(object.getString("dish_name"));


         menu_name.add(object.getString("menu_title"));

                            day.add(object.getString("day"));
                            count = count + 1;

String[] mVal = new String[school.length()];

    for (int k = 0; k < school.length(); k++) {
    mVal[k] = school.getJSONObject(k).getString("menu_title");
        message = "weekly";
            mVal2 = mVal[0];



                            }











@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.e01:
            new getDataTask().execute();

        break;





                 public class thirdstepAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;

String[] Main_menu;

public thirdstepAdapter(Activity act) {
    this.activity = act;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  return Main_menu.length;
    return thirdstep.Category_ID.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtText);

    holder.txtText.setText(thirdstep.dish_name.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtText;
}

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

> notifyDataSetChanged();

For example

```
 Arraylist<String> data=new Arraylist<String>();
Mycustum_adaptor adapter = new Mycustum_adaptor (data);

    yourlistview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Set adaptor like this on the first time. And for example if you add a new data to array list **data** like this.

```
data.add("newdata");
```

So you Adapter need to know A change has occur so use **notifyDataSetChanged();** like below

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will Refresh the list view with new data added.Notify the data set change after u add or remove any data from you adaptor.
Hope this will help you

Comment: where i place adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()   above this line or below this line     yourlistview.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: only after setting your adaptor first.

Comment: you need to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after u make changes in your data.then only the list view will get updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on your `Adapter`, which I don't really see in your code.

Comment: @smartguy Anytime you add some data to what the adapter should be displaying.

Comment: emil my listview show duplicate data if i click multiple time on button

Comment: give me snapshot a t which place i add notifyDataSetChanged() on postexecute or on background??

Comment: @smartguy I'm trying to give you a hint, but I'm not about to read all the code you posted - it is quite unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

after adding item or removing pass list of item again to list adapter

Comment: call this after changes listCategory.setAdapter(cla);

Comment: u mean after thids line
 listCategory.setAdapter(cla)  write notifyDataSetChanged()???

Answer (score 0):

After setting the values in your listview you need to clear the arraylist in your `getDataTask()` method. As you are not clearing the Arraylist that is the only reason it shows the duplicate values.

> ```
>      @Override
> protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
>     if ((Category_ID.size() > 0) || IOConnect == 0) {
>         listCategory.setAdapter(cla);
>        clearData();
>     }
> ```

Also modify your `clearData()` as below:

> ```
>    void clearData() {
>          Category_ID.clear();
>           Category_ID=null;
>          school_name.clear();
>          school_name=null;
>          menu_name.clear();
>          menu_name=null;
>          dish_name.clear();
>          dish_name=null;
>          day.clear();
>          day=null;  
>          Vacation_ID.clear();
>          Vacation_ID=null;
>          Vacation_name.clear();
>          Vacation_name=null;
>          Vacation_Date.clear();
>          Vacation_Date=null;
> }
> ```

Comment: Just try to write the cleardata after the execution of `getDataTask` in your button click.